# Roth Siegel Thue application

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Consider $$\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-(k+1+3^k)}$$

I think one can easily show using the Roth Siegel Thue theorem that $\alpha$ is transcendental because the irrationality exponent of $\alpha$ is almost $3$ and certainly above $2$. But since I have never dealt with these methods before I am seeking a confirmation here: is $\alpha$ above transcendental?

Many thanks in advance, Martin.

Comment: In the binary representation of $\alpha$ there are an infinite number of $1$s, but the distance between a digit $1$ and the next digit $1$ is arbitrarily large. It is not difficult to prove that the same property is shared by $p(\alpha)$ for any non-constant $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, hence yes, $\alpha$ is trascendental.